# What s the best way Streaming Live Video & Audio?

Tags: video-streaming, audio-streaming

I already know how to stream video from my iphone to my cocoa server. it's simple because videos come in different frames, and i can transfer them 1 by 1.

1- But how does the audio streaming works, how can i separate the data being read from microphone without interrupting the data?

2- How can i make sure that the audio matches the video, and keep the timing between them?

This is not a duplicate, there are questions with the same title, but the details are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The audio comes back from the OS in buffer data blocks of some length (duration of which is partially configurable) which you can transfer 1 by 1 just like the video.  You can queue up and rechunk the blocks as necessary.  If you attach a header to each audio transfer block, you can tag the audio data with a time stamp and/or the contemporaneous video frame capture ID.